# Access ControlTemplate item by Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button:

```
<Button Name="btnPlayPause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Margin="8,10,0,0" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnPlayPause_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Name="btnPlayPause_Image" Source="Images/Pause.png"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

I want to change the `Image` (in the ControlTemplate) in C#. I am doing it like:

```
//changing icon
BitmapImage iconPlay = new BitmapImage();
iconPlay.BeginInit();
iconPlay.UriSource = new Uri("images\\Play.png", UriKind.Relative);
iconPlay.EndInit();

btnPlayPause_Image.Source = iconPlay;
```

But I can't access `btnPlayPause_Image`. It Says **It doesn't exists in the current context**.

But why??

When I create button without `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Button Name="btnPlayPause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Margin="8,10,0,0" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnPlayPause_Click">
    <Image Name="btnPlayPause_Image" Source="Images/Pause.png"/>
</Button>
```

C# Code works fine. It finds the `btnPlayPause_Image` and changes the image source successfully:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image` is not in the scope of the window. It's in the scope of the Template of the Button. So you have to use the method `FindName` of the Button's Template like this:

```
var img = btnPlayPause.Template.FindName("btnPlayPause_Image", btnPlayPause) as Image;   //second parameter is the "ParentTemplate"
if(img != null) img.Source = iconPlay;
```

Comment: It takes one more argument. `ParentTemplate`. I fixed it.